# Stream.publish ogg

Tags: facebook, audio, stream, publish, ogg

i'm trying to publish ogg audio files to the stream using javascript api and FB.ui,
but i can't figure out how to do it.
Here is my call to FB.ui :

```
FB.ui(
      {
        method: 'stream.publish',
        message: '',
        attachment: {
            name: artist + ' - ' + song,
            "media" : [{
                "type":"mp3" ,
                "src" :  file,
                "artist" : artist,
                    "title" : song
            }]
        }

      },
      function(response) {
      }
    );
```

With media type set as "mp3" the file just doesn't play, and after lot of looking around i can't figure out another audio type to specify.
Is it possible to share ogg files ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem. Streaming ogg and would like it to show up when I share the link of my page. Trying now through OpenGraph, I could manage the player to show up in the shared link but the stream doesn't seem to work. Probably as OffBySome mentioned, they might only support mp3. Hope only for now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure only mp3 format is supported. I have never seen .ogg mentioned in the documentation.